# Forbiding Git from overwriting a file

Tags: git

Let's say I have an application which need some secret data to work properly, like a web service which needs login/password to connect to the database, and the code of such app is stored on Git server. For obvious security reasons I put all secret stuff in file 'secret.txt' which I call from the app. The file 'secret.txt' isn't in the repo, but references to it is in the code (so everyone knows there is a 'secret.txt' file, but they can't find it in the repo).

Now imagine some malicious user put his own 'secret.txt' file in the repo and I didn't found it. Does it mean that, when I `git fetch` on the production server, the file will be overwritten? If that so, how can I forbid git from replacing the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git will show you error if there is already an untracked file with the same name present at the same path.

Comment: What if I put 'secret.txt' in ```.gitignore```? And the malicious change both ```.gitignore``` and 'secret.txt'?

Comment: in wither of the case since you already have a file.. git will ask you to either remove the other file or to merge them.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with the following approach:

1. Create a file `secrets.txt` on the server.
2. Read that file on the server instead of the file which is present on github
3. In case of code deployment or git clone, first you clone the code, then copy secrets.txt from server to the directory where you have cloned the code.